# Given the times needed by two workers to complete a task, how long will they need to do it together?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Jeff probably is hard-working person and finish his job within $a$ hours and his friend Joe, ends the same job within $b$ hours.
Now, if they work together job is done by $$\frac{ab}{a+b}$$ hours of working.
Why ?
I'll appreciate any illustration by proving the statement.
Thank you!

Comment: Does this help : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/496960/working-rate-problem ?

Comment: Thank you too !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one hour $(a,b>0)$:

- Jeff will complete $\dfrac{1}{a}$  of the work (there is ONE job).
- Joe will complete $\dfrac{1}{b}$  of the work.
- Jeff and Joe will complete $\dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{1}{b}=\dfrac{a+b}{ab}$ of the work together.

So the time needed when two people work together to complete that ONE job is $1\div\dfrac{a+b}{ab}=\dfrac{ab}{a+b}$ hours.

Comment: Then, isn't $$\frac{ab}{a+b}$$ amount of work done in ONE hour?

Comment: No, $\dfrac{a+b}{ab}$ is the amount of work done, $\dfrac{ab}{a+b}$ is the time taken in hours.

Comment: I can't understand last part. Where you've done this.  $$1\div\frac{a+b}{ab}$$

Comment: There is $x$ job, if you can do $y$ job per hour (job/hour), then the hours taken to complete the job is $x\div y$. This is a variation of traveling, when the road is $x$ km long and you ride a vehicle for $y$ km per hour then you will need $x\div y$ hours to finish

Comment: Thank you for your time!